# How to interpret subtleties between sentences on 'faith' and 'theology' - Why was this closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, reopen

I beg for your forgiveness if [How to interpret subtleties between sentences on 'faith' and 'theology'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/36526/8712) offends, but I'd like to request its reopening. I'm asking only about English (and not anything about religion) in that article, because I suspect that I've confused, misinterpreted, and failed to differentiate the meaning of the 3 sentences.

Does user TRomano's supportive comment that I thank, explain why my question was closed?

> This question has nothing to do with questions about religious opinion. You guys are wrong in labeling it that way.

Answer (score 6):

I refer you to [my answer](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1215/32) to a previous Meta question of yours, where I wrote

> In the specific question at hand, for instance, [the examiners] ask what inferences you can draw from what the author has written. These are not matters of linguistic analysis but of logical and rhetorical analysis. They are not suited to this site.

The same is true of this question: you do not ask us what the language means or how it means it, but what legitimate inferences can be drawn from the meaning expressed. We do not hold ourselves out here as experts on logic and rhetoric; consequently, what you ask us for is non-linguistic opinon.

The question was properly closed.

Comment: I agreed with the close vote for this question. Questions should be focused on the language. We can help with things like confusing phrases and unusual sentence construction, but this isn't the place to ask for help understanding the passage as a whole. Our goal here is to build up a repository of knowledge to help English language learners. This particular question has no language knowledge that could be useful to another advanced English learner - it's only helpful to folks studying for tests with reading comprehension questions.